# linux mysql convert .sql.tar.gz to csv

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, convert

I have a .sql.tar.gz file tht ws generated by mysql export

is there any command in linux to convert this sql.tar.gz file to csv?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try to export MySQL data as CSV and no need to look for a tool for conversion.

Even if you don't have the original MySQL database table, you can restore the SQL file and then export it as CSV. This is the best way to do it.

Comment: I just have the file now

Comment: Then you need to import it into a MySQL server and generate CSV export from the server. There isn't any other good way to do it.